# How to complete a graph ggplot2

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2

I´m doing a graph to show a number of hits to some websites. I´ve the following data frame:

```
  Time1  Time2 Sitio    hits    Time
1   2014-4-11   8:0 Gmail   1   2014-04-11 08:00:00
2   2014-4-11   8:0 Google  18  2014-04-11 08:00:00
3   2014-4-11   8:0 Twitter 4   2014-04-11 08:00:00
4   2014-4-11   8:0 Facebook    13  2014-04-11 08:00:00
5   2014-4-11   8:0 Youtube.com 110 2014-04-11 08:00:00
6   2014-4-11   8:0 Mediavida.com   3   2014-04-11 08:00:00
7   2014-4-11   8:0 Grooveshark.com 4   2014-04-11 08:00:00
8   2014-4-11   8:0 teleconlanparty.org 20  2014-04-11 08:00:00
9   2014-4-11   7:56    Twitter 2   2014-04-11 07:56:00
10  2014-4-11   7:56    Facebook    6   2014-04-11 07:56:00
11  2014-4-11   7:56    Youtube.com 8   2014-04-11 07:56:00
12  2014-4-11   7:56    teleconlanparty.org 11  2014-04-11 07:56:00
13  2014-4-11   7:57    Gmail   36  2014-04-11 07:57:00
14  2014-4-11   7:57    Google  1   2014-04-11 07:57:00
15  2014-4-11   7:57    Twitter 79  2014-04-11 07:57:00
16  2014-4-11   7:57    Facebook    194 2014-04-11 07:57:00
17  2014-4-11   7:57    Series.ly   2   2014-04-11 07:57:00
18  2014-4-11   7:57    Hotmail.com 81  2014-04-11 07:57:00
19  2014-4-11   7:57    Meneame.com 4   2014-04-11 07:57:00
20  2014-4-11   7:57    Youtube.com 173 2014-04-11 07:57:00
21  2014-4-11   7:57    Mediavida.com   12  2014-04-11 07:57:00
22  2014-4-11   7:57    teleconlanparty.org 95  2014-04-11 07:57:00
23  2014-4-11   7:58    Gmail   34  2014-04-11 07:58:00
24  2014-4-11   7:58    Google  13  2014-04-11 07:58:00
25  2014-4-11   7:58    Twitter 83  2014-04-11 07:58:00
26  2014-4-11   7:58    Facebook    99  2014-04-11 07:58:00
27  2014-4-11   7:58    Series.ly   2   2014-04-11 07:58:00
28  2014-4-11   7:58    Hotmail.com 5   2014-04-11 07:58:00
29  2014-4-11   7:58    Meneame.com 1   2014-04-11 07:58:00
30  2014-4-11   7:58    Youtube.com 247 2014-04-11 07:58:00
```

I´m doing a graph that every web has a line:

```
ggplot(traficoweb, aes(Time,Hits,colour=Sitio)) + geom_line() 

![incomplete representation][1]
```

But some websites are not visited every minute so they are not defined sometimes. I would like     to assign 0 when the website is not visited for one minute. Thereby, I could do the graph properly.

Thanks for helping!!!

Comment: do your data prep before plotting.

Comment: I´ve analysed my data with Apache Pig. But I don´t know how to count the minutes that don't have packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the transformation before you try to plot. You can create a list of all the times and sites and merge them to create the missing rows. For example (Assuming that your Time column is a proper POSIXct time class)

```
alltime<-seq(min(traficoweb$Time), max(traficoweb$Time), by="1 min")
mm<-merge(traficoweb, 
    expand.grid(Sitio=unique(traficoweb$Sitio), Time=alltime), all.y=T)
mm$hits[is.na(mm$hits)]<-0
```

Then just plot with

```
ggplot(mm, aes(Time,hits,colour=Sitio)) + geom_line()
```

[image]